# How can I put code into my .js.snapshot file so that a value updates?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, snapshot

My code has a test.js.snap file, and a copyright date. I want it to not have to constantly be changed so I can keep my tests as is.

So far, the file has:

```
        <ul>
          <p>
            <span>
              Copyright © 2017 My Company. All rights reserved.
            </span>
          </p>
        </ul>
```

However, I need this current year. I could hardcode the update, but then each year I would need to change it. I was tempted to put `{new Date().getFullYear()}` in place of `2017` but that's not proper code I think. How can I do this?

Comment: Why isn't `new Date().getFullYear()` the "proper" code?  It gives me the current year.

Comment: where should I put it? Should it be in curly braces? This is a test.js.snap file